yarn install forcing latest version of @angular-devkit/schematics
I'm using Angular 17. in my package.json I only use angulat 17 packages with Material
"dependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/core": "^17.3.3",
  "@angular-magic/ngx-gp-autocomplete": "^2.0.2",
  "@angular/animations": "^17.3.3",
  "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.3",
  "@angular/common": "^17.3.3",
  "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.3",
  "@angular/core": "^17.3.3",
  "@angular/forms": "^17.3.3",
  "@angular/material": "^17.3.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.3",
  "@angular/router": "^17.3.3",
  "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.19",
  "@googlemaps/js-api-loader": "^1.16.6",
  "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.9",
  "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.9",
  "@types/diff": "^5.0.9",
  "apexcharts": "^3.42.0",
  "chart.js": "^4.4.0",
  "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.2.0",
  "deep-equal": "^2.2.2",
  "deep-object-diff": "^1.1.9",
  "diff": "^5.1.0",
  "diff-match-patch-ts": "^0.3.0",
  "diff2html": "^3.4.47",
  "json-diff": "^1.0.6",
  "json-diff-ts": "^1.2.6",
  "jsondiffpatch": "^0.5.0",
  "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
  "ng-apexcharts": "^1.8.0",
  "ng2-charts": "4.1.1",
  "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^12.0.1",
  "ngx-object-diff": "^0.0.3",
  "ngx-tag-commander": "^3.0.0",
  "ngx-text-diff": "^0.6.0",
  "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
  "storybook": "^1.0.0",
  "tslib": "^2.3.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.14.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.3",
  "@angular/cli": "^17.3.3",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.3",
  "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
  "@ngneat/spectator": "^5.13.3",
  "@ngrx/effects": "^17.1.1",
  "@ngrx/entity": "^9.2.0",
  "@ngrx/schematics": "^9.2.0",
  "@ngrx/store": "^17.1.1",
  "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^17.1.1",
  "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.9",
  "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.22",
  "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.9",
  "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.9",
  "@storybook/angular": "^6.1.21",
  "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
  "@types/google.maps": "^3.55.5",
  "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "@types/node": "^12.12.61",
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.27.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.27.0",
  "autoprefixer": "^10.4.19",
  "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
  "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
  "eslint": "^7.28.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
  "karma": "~6.3.17",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
  "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
  "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
  "ng-mocks": "^14.12.1",
  "postcss": "^8.4.24",
  "protractor": "~7.0.0",
  "sinon": "^9.0.3",
  "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
  "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
  "tslint": "~6.1.3",
  "typescript": "~5.2.2"
}

When I use yarn install I'm getting this issue :

error @angular-devkit/schematics@18.2.8: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "^18.19.1 || ^20.11.1 || >=22.0.0". Got "18.16.0"
error Found incompatible module.

I'm not allowed to upgrade my node version.
I don't know why it's using @18.2.8 version.
I have tried to install @angular-devkit/schematics": "^17.3.10", but it's keeping installing @angular-devkit/schematics@18.2.8
How can I force it to use the v17 version ?

issue not reproducible on stackblitz -> cd test -> yarn install, try deleting node_modules, package-lock.json, clear cache and then install

I think I get it , because of "rxjs": "~7.4.0", >>~<< which asked 7.8.x which depend of @angular-devkit/schematics@18.2.8, deleting ~ resolved the issue

Thanks for the post. Had the same issue, but for me it was @compodoc library that was installing angular version 18.2.8. And forcing the node upgrade.

yes compodoc was making this issue too
